# Javascript Search form not displaying when form input is cleared?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

If you go to http://app.collegeconnect.ph/sortsearch?sortby=HightoLow&rankingsortby=HightoLow&searchItem=&criteria=

Use the "Tuition Fees Range" filter (click any option, though I would recommend the first or second one), then click Apply Filter.  You will see the search results AND the search form at the top.

Click "Clear" under the Tuition Fees Range filter and then click Apply Filter.

The search form at the top disappears and you just see the buttons that control the forms.

Chrome console shows the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
Uncaught ReferenceError: openCity is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (sortsearch?sortby=HightoLow&rankingsortby=HightoLow&searchItem=&criteria=:92)
at sortsearch?sortby=HightoLow&rankingsortby=HightoLow&searchItem=&criteria=:1495
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Basically, a person MUST select an option under the Tuition Fees Range filter in order for the the search form to show.  Not sure how get the search form to show even if the filter is cleared and a person uses the other filters.

Here's the code for the searchController: https://paste.ee/p/jE6DR

the blade file: https://paste.ee/p/5pY7W

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just dumped onto an eternal site.

Comment: Whether you apply filtration or not, your page is having error in console.

Comment: @Kamal I'm trying to figure out what causes the error in console.  And if you read my problem, you would know that the filter does have some relation to the error in the console.

Comment: @CBroe - ok, I have no idea what aspects of my code may be causing the problem so if I put all of the code into the post, will you be willing to remove the downvote?

Comment: One of your DOM tries to find openCity function but it is missing from your page, so you should include that function or remove reference of openCity if it is not needed.

Comment: That'll depend very much on whether you manage to address the other issues How to Ask explains as well.

Comment: @CBroe thats very discouraging.

Comment: @Kamal the function is not missing when I apply the Tuition Range filter on the page.  but for some reason it goes missing when I clear the filter.

Comment: Do me your favor, open the link & don't apply any filtration  and check Chrome console, you'll see the same error on page load..

Comment: Go to this page: http://app.collegeconnect.ph/sortsearch?FeesRange=0+-+10000&sortby=HightoLow&rankingsortby=HightoLow&searchItem=&criteria=  You will only see one error in console.

Comment: The JS syntax error you have produced in the lines before that, and that the browser console mentions first as well, is causing the parser not to "find" your function declaration any more. So fix _that_. And take away the lesson that you _always_ fix errors in the order they occur in, you never go "ah, that has probably nothing to do with it" ...

Comment: _"You will only see one error in console."_ - that one is another case of simply messed up JavaScript syntax - so you have to go look at the server-side part of your code that creates this output. In this case it is really as simple as a single `}` left over at the very end of that script block, and the commenting-out of lines going on there suggests that might be the result of some debug efforts.